# HTML Basics: Why is div not scaling to 100%

Tags: html

I don't see any reason why this snippet doesn't scale to 100 percent of the screen...does anyone know...i guess so...I just don't get it  and here a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uuzbv/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
body{
width:100%;
height:100%;}

.section{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#000;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="section">

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By the way, you can put CSS into the top right box in a jsFiddle. It'll automatically apply it all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
body, html {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding to the html dom element.  It's hard to tell without any content.

```
*{width:100%;height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

use of property `width:100%` on html,body and section(if want to stretch full viewport) is reluctant or not needed coz by default they all are stretched to full viewport.
u can set the height of desired pixels like `height: required pixels` or can also use nonbreaking spaces `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 1):

It's the nature of positioning. By default your elements are set as `position:static`, which basically says that the element will be positioned as it occurs in the document. Therefore, the percentage height you defined in the `&lt;body&gt;` element has to obey the height rules set by the `&lt;html&gt;` element. Which in this case is essentially the default empty element height.  If you notice, setting the position on the body to something like `absolute or fixed` will suddenly extend the box (whereas `relative` won't). This is because you are removing it from the normal flow of the page.

However, as most have pointed out, setting the height / width of the html, and body element will fix this issue, which is what I recommend. In fact, on most pages I do I usually start with:

```
html, body{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}
```

This will basically give you the full window space to work with inside the body of the page.